# Loss of knowledge using HMVC (Kohana)

Tags: php, kohana, hmvc

I have a questions regarding the HMVC model by Kohana. I really like the idea of separating stuff as components within the same principles (MVC) for scaling and easier api creation.

Though there are some drawbacks I’m experiencing like loss of knowledge.

For example, I could have components called **news** and **categories**. On top of that are the site controllers that just delegate the full request and gathers all html/data for the site templates through these components.

```
          Site controller
           /             \
          /               \
   categories              news
```

When I want all categories for a sidebar, I could call: /categories/list. When I want a news item I could call /news/ID. Both return html.

If I have a newsreadon site controller which main task is to show a news article, this controller will get all categories for the sidebar. Next it will fetch the news item.

```
                Newsreadon
               /          \
              /            \
 categories/list (html)    news/<id>   (html)
```

When I display all elements within the site template I want to know the 'title' of the news for the html title tag, but I can't know because I return html.

I feel like there are multiple solutions:

1. Store title in some registry (but this is lost if I scale the component to a other server and use HTTP). So in view of scaling, no good choice.
2. Return json with 'title' and 'html' fields.
3. Read out some part of the html like h2 for the title

Solution 2 seems to be the least nasty and keeps the stateless communication in tact.

I'm really wondering how **you** would solve this in a elegant way? Am I missing 'the' solution?

EDIT:
Interesting read to understand HMVC by kohana:
http://techportal.inviqa.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a newsreadon site controller which main task is to show a
>   news article...

If this controllers' purpose is to display a news article then I don't understand the need for an additional controller. Consider changing your application design, perhaps Newsreadon extends the controller to display the news article.

Comment: Newsreadon just builds up the website with different widget elements. I can't make newsreadon extend news because news is build as a internal request that can be scaled to a other server easily. It should be separated by hmvc design otherwise i can't take advantage of the hmvc-advantages that rely on the HTTP protocol for internal and external use.

Comment: I understand the concepts, I did not understand your situation correctly. If you are wanting structured data, other than just a chunk of html, then consider using a data interchange format, like JSON.

Comment: Was afraid this would be the only solution. I think I might build it up as "title" and "html". If I only give json data back (no html markup) my site needs to create the html while this perfectly fits within the component too

Answer (score -1):

Since you display the news using `news/<id>`, presumably the parent controller knows the ID of the news. From that, just get the news title from your model. That would be the proper way to do it. Trying to extract some data from sub-requests will make your application more tightly coupled and more difficult to maintain on the long run.

Comment: But i see news as 'widget'. If i let the newsreadon controller access the model, then I have 2 controllers that access the model and in the worst case the database if there aint proper caching. This sounds as extra coupling to me.

Comment: @mauserrifle, I wouldn't worry about the application accessing the same model twice, because it can be easily optimized (as you said, it can be cached). Two-ways dependencies between requests or controllers however cannot be optimized in an obvious way. Basically, you have two controllers that need to access the same data - they should access this data directly through the model, and not by making assumption about what the other controller is doing.

Comment: I understand your point of view and made me hesitate. But I do worry because if a widget/component ever gets scaled to a other server, I rather not want the site controller do any business with this model directly. So just get data from the component, display it and eventually maybe pass POST requests to the component. This way it's seperated and the website is just a client for the component. We have plans to make a mobile application in the future and with this way of separating, the component can do all business and the website and the mobile app are just clients using the same gateway.